# Set Today date to kendo datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I want to set today date to Kendo DatePicker on clear button click. I tried following but it is not working.

```
$('#btnClear').click(function () {
  $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(new Date());
});
```

Above code don't give any error and don't set today date. It clears kendo DatePicker's textbox value.
Note: Kendo DatePicker format is MM/dd/yyyy.

Comment: @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
          .Name("startDate").Value(DateTime.Today))

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I tried following and works perfectly for me.

```
$('#btnClear').click(function () {
  var todayDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date()), 'MM/dd/yyyy');
  $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate);
});
```

Comment: Very clear and concise answer. $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate); worked for me except I had to use `.val(todayDate)` instead of `.value(todayDate)`

Comment: In countries that use dd/MM/yyyy format, use `var todayDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date()), 'dd/MM/yyyy');`

Comment: after an afternoon of problems with the format of dates, that's the solution! thank you!

Comment: When I do this, it starts an infinite loop.

Comment: Another option is to use the native way: var today = kendo.date.today();

Answer (score 11):

```
 $('#btnClear').click(function (e) {
  var todayDate = new Date();
  $('#StartDate').data("kendoDatePicker").value(todayDate);
                                  });
```

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: If this doesn't work for you - make sure you're not setting `max: new Date` which will likely be before the Date you're trying to set as "now".

Answer (score 5):

After setting the value of the datepicker, you need to trigger the change event of the datePicker e.g:

```
$("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker").trigger("change");
```

Explanation from Telerik:

> "The DatePicker will not apply the "new" date if it is the same as its
>   internal value. When you call the date in the method [they mean by using *datepicker*.value(*myDate*)] and just set its
>   date, then the internal date of the DatePicker is set too"

See also http://www.telerik.com/forums/datepicker-does-not-update-the-value-in-view

Answer (score 3):

I have use it like -

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                  .Name("customerOrderDate")
                  .Min(DateTime.Today)
                  .Value(Model.CustomerOrderDate)
                  .HtmlAttributes(new {style = "width:120px"}))
```

It is good part that Kendo have DateTime struct in their api.

Answer (score 3):

The answer didn't work for me it wasn't until I triggered a change event before it set.

```
var datePicker = $("#StartDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
var todayDate = new Date();                                   
datePicker.value(todayDate);
datePicker.trigger("change"); // <-- This one did the trick
```

Answer (score -2):

Please See this Example 
May Be helpful to you

http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/web/DatePicker.html

Comment: link you should give in comment otherwise few people can downvote you.

Comment: for comment minimum 50 reputation needed . and i have 23 that's why i Give the answer . Is That Helpful  ?

Comment: that i know but other won't consider this.