# How can I display current date in kendo-date-picker as the default selected value

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-datepicker

I want to show current date as default selected value in kendo-date-picker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Today date to kendo datepicker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337509/set-today-date-to-kendo-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Kendo date control doesn't support default values.
Instead, you can try to set the value of your kendo control by JQuery or Javascript.
You can try :

```
window.onload = function () {
 var actualDate = kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(new Date()), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
 $("#myKendoDateControl").data("kendoDatePicker").value(actualDate);
}
```