# How to update Kendo datepicker value from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, kendo-datepicker

I have a kendo-datepicker. I want to update its value using JavaScript.
Following is the control in HTML:

```
  <kendo-datepicker [(value)]="departureDate" (valueChange)="changeDepartureDate()" [disabled]="readOnly" id="Depdate" ></kendo-datepicker>
```

Following is the JavaScript code

```
 var aa = new Date(this.selectedFfDeparture.date).getFullYear() + "-" + new Date(this.selectedFfDeparture.date).getMonth() + "-" + new Date(this.selectedFfDeparture.date).getDate();
  alert(aa);

  (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('Depdate')).value = aa;
  alert((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('Depdate')).value);
```

It is working fine with normal input of type date but not with Kendo. But weird thing is that i am able to set its value even in alert it shows that value has been changed but not shows in Kendo control.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Today date to kendo datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337509/set-today-date-to-kendo-datepicker)

Comment: yes i visited that link but i dont know what kendo is in that solution